# Multiple select text "0 objects"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have a select box with multiple attribute, here is an example:

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="all-item" selected>All</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

On laptop everything works fine but on mobile browser, there is automatically added text like "0 items" or, "3 items" (after selecting some items). Same like here:

[image]

How can I change this text to e.g "3 Filters" ?

Regards.

Comment: Are you using a plugin for the multiple select control?

Comment: No, because I'm writing web page in GWT (Java framework) so probably I cannot use the external plugin. Finally my Java code (written in GWT) is parsed to HTML but I tried also with normal HTML (https://jsfiddle.net/swng34wq/ ) and there is the same problem check on mobile phone browser).

Comment: Well that text is coming from the library controlling the select. You will need to amend the value in the settings there - assuming it even allows you to do that

Comment: But the question is, how can i do this?

Comment: I just mentioned how you do it in my previous comment. You've not given us enough information, nor a sample of the actual code that builds the select, in order for anyone to show you exactly how to code it.

Comment: Because there is no logic and nothing more (i'm working on that now). The same case is here: https://jsfiddle.net/swng34wq/
so you can check it.

Comment: That's clearly not the same code which is creating the UI in your image